# Automapper table mapping Table 0..1-* Relationship

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, automapper

I have been using Automapper in our projects and just recently ran into an issue not previously encountered.

When the table I am trying to Map has a 0..1 TO * relationship Automapper is not performing the mapping.

I tried examining and altering the CreateMap call and the lambda expression of the .ForMember(..) is not allowing me to access the tableObject's properties.

Can someone point me to the right direction on this?

I checked another table that I hadn't tried using in our model which is also 0..1 TO 1 and noticed the same problem.

Thanks,

Victor

EDIT:
Found the issue... the two classes were coincidentally incorrectly setup. They were public but didn't have any public properties (the public keyword was ommitted for all properties).

I tried to provide an answer but don't have enough reputation for self-answer in < 8hrs.

Thanks,
Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue... the two classes were coincidentally incorrectly setup. They were public but didn't have any public properties (the public keyword was ommitted for all properties).

I tried to provide an answer but don't have enough reputation for self-answer in < 8hrs.

Thanks, Victor